# How to lock the app from minimize and exit in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an app in react native. I want to lock the app from minimize and exit, I mean that when the user press the home button or the back button nothing happened and it will stay in the same screen.

I was looking a lot and nothing came up but the **BackHandler** that cancel only the back button but not the minimize and there how button

```
 BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
  return true;
})
```

I need the change will be **by the code** and not configuration one..

**I'm not talking about Orientation to landscape or portrait**

Thank you for the help

Comment: You can't on iOS. Locking the device to a single app has to be done via a supervision profile or by the user with guided access. On iOS there is also an app lock mode that can be used if your app is a testing app used in education

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your answer.. what about android?

Comment: There *probably* is a way for android to disable it from home and back buttons, but there are other ways to exit the app for android. But anyway, your app will be banned really fast if you implement such a malicious behavior. User has to be able to exit the app **whenever he wants**

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the app is not actually for many user the main goal is to show only one screen all the time without anyone touch it...

Comment: I believe Android has a kiosk mode, but this isn't something available to developers. https://developer.android.com/work/cosu

Comment: as PPartisan noted, you want to use a kiosk mode, if you want to distribute your own devices with pre-installed this app.

Comment: @PPartisan what part I should look for in the kiosk to make sure the user will not be able to exit or minimize the app?

Comment: @TalShani- I've never used it personally, I'm just aware of its existence. Your best bet is to read the documentation I linked.